# Compare and concatenate duplicate values in excel using VBA

Tags: duplicates, concatenation

I have a report in an excel format that has case number field in a one to many relationship with other fields. For ex: If a case is worked by multiple teams, it has separate entries for each team.

I'm trying to remove the duplicates by concatenating the row values by comparing the case number.

**Case#   Team   Type  Name  Country**

111        aa      xx   Name  country

111        bb      yy   Name  country

I want the output to be:

**Case #**   **Type**  **Team**    **Name**  **Country**

111            aa,bb       xx,yy      Name      country

I have the VBA code below:

```
Sub mergeCaseNumberValues()
Dim lngRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    Dim columnToMatch As Integer: columnToMatch = 1

    lngRow = .Cells(65536, columnToMatch).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(columnToMatch).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(columnToMatch), Header:=xlYes
    Do
        If .Cells(lngRow, columnToMatch) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, columnToMatch) Then

            For i = 2 To 12
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = .Cells(lngRow, i).Value & .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value

            Next i
            .Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If
        lngRow = lngRow - 1
    Loop Until lngRow = 1
End With
End Sub
```

It is giving me :

Case#   Type     Team   Name      Country

111      aabb    xxyy   NameName  countrycountry

In the data, only the team and type differ with each entry, other values are the same. How do i modify my VBA to obtain the result? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this:

```
        For i = 2 To 12
        .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = .Cells(lngRow, i).Value & .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value
```

to this:

```
        For i = 2 To 12
        .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = .Cells(lngRow, i).Value & ", " & .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value
```

You need to fix the concatenator to insert the comma.

For your issue with repeating, I think something like this might work.  Keep in mind it's "air code", completely untested but should get you in the right direction:

```
        For i = 2 To 12
          If .Cells(lngRow, i).Value <> .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value Then
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = .Cells(lngRow, i).Value & ", " & .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value
          Else 
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, i).Value = .Cells(lngRow, i).Value
          End If
```

Basically, you want to compare the values using an IF statement, and if they're equal then you don't want to take them both.

Comment: yes,thank you Johnny. you are right about the syntax for concatenation but I'm still having trouble in having the values replaced when there is a match.